# How to properly extend joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm trying to extend joomla 3 but I don't have any idea how to do it properly. What I need are some new tables in the database, so far they are complete but I have used another prefix that joomla itself to prevent collisions. Now I want to make an interface where a guest can browse and filter the data in there and also an option for admins to insert new data, which needs to be joined semanticly so I cannot use a query generator. Is there any good practice to solve such an issue? I began writing a module but at half way it doesn't seem to be the best solution to do all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should be looking into `component` development.

A module usually only concerns itself with the display of data, with the ability to add a small amount of parameters to a single database field, whereas a component allows you to create multiple views and so play with whichever database rows and tables you want.

Sometimes you would need both a component and a module, with the module used to display the component data to the site users. Components replace the main article area, but modules are used for smaller widget areas.

In terms of learning, you are probably best starting with module development as components build on this knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a [component](https://docs.joomla.org/Component) should be more appropriate for your task than writing a module, as there you can control the main content of the cms.

From the Joomla documentation:

> Modules are only "small boxes" arranged around components.
>
> A component is a kind of Joomla! extension. Components are the main
>   functional units of Joomla!;

See the Joomla tutorial [Developing a MVC Component/Developing a Basic Component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component).

A simpler, but less clean way for that task would be to [write a plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla). For example you could write one to modify the article's behavior and inject your own content into an article before it is displayed to the user, see the [onContentBeforeDisplay event](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentBeforeDisplay).

An alternative to programming is to use a content construction kit (CCK), that are powerful extensions you simply install in Joomla. You can create new content types and could also inject data from your database.
For example I created a new type "publication" with title, author, description, ... fields and used that type to display the content of my custom database.
I used [Seblod](http://www.seblod.com/) for that, but there are others too. I think the most popular is [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/k2).